# Formatting console output from Test::Unit

Tags: ruby, webdriver, testunit

```
require "json"
require "selenium-webdriver"
gem "test-unit"
require "test/unit"

class Tests < Test::Unit::TestCase

$out_file = File.new('log.txt', 'w')

def $stdout.write string
  $out_file.write string
  super
end
```

When I use the above code the output in the console looks great but when it's finished it dumps everything into my log file (like I expect) but the format in the log file comes out with strange extra characters at the end.  The first two lines below are as expected but the third is ???

First Run - Main: 1.998

First Run - Drill Through: 16.527

[32;1m.[0m

I've been fishing around for some options and I've tried to configure the test-unit.yml file fiddling with the format options below but no matter what I try there nothing changes the format of the output.

runner: console
console_options:
  output_level: 1
  format: documentation
  show_detail_immediately: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[32;1m` and in general any `[((\d+);?)m` is the color escape sequence. They highlight the output in your console. `[32;1m.[0m` is literally a **green dot**, denoting successful test execution.

There are three ways to handle them:

#### Set the [`tty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-tty-3F) attribute to false on the output stream

This will make a perfect log file, but you’ll lose any color highlighting in the console itself.

#### Use different writers for console and file

This is a long way round and seem to be an overkill for your approach.

#### Filter out escape sequences

I would go with:

```
$out_file.write string.gsub /\[[\d;]+m/, ''
```

The above will filter any crap out and you’ll get the plain old-school text in your file.